# How to log in async/await context

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs, puppeteer

I wonder why my second `console.log()` not logs anything to the console...

```
describe('Puppeteer', () => {
  it('Does not log', () => {
    (async () => {
      console.log('This logs'); // <- works
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: [
          '--incognito'
        ]
      });
      await console.log('This does not log'); // <- Does not work
      console.log('This does not log too'); // <- This neither
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('....');
      ....
      expect(a < b)
        .toEqual(true);
      browser.close();
    })();
  });
});
```

Is there any reason why that does not log?

Comment: @Shubham there is no way to log?

Comment: Possible misunderstanding on the difference between async and sync ?

Comment: @Shubham `await` works with sync values too(it works like `await Promise.resolve(<value here>)`)

Comment: it's strange. does any next code like `browser.close()` run?

Comment: While it's true `console.log` doesn't return a Promise, you can still `await` non-Promises just fine, at least in normal JS - what makes this situation different?

Comment: looks like your browser launch never resolves

Comment: change like this:  it('Does not log', async () => {});

Comment: Lol I just wrote an answer and saw this comment. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** This does not work because you are running the block instantly. Make sure to pass a function which is not self executing.

A example of  self executing function is `(()=>{})()`. This prevents the test from resolving properly.

Here is the cleaned up code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const assert = require('assert');

describe('Puppeteer', () => {
  it('Does log', async () => { // <== PASS THE FUNCTION HERE
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--incognito']});
      console.log('This logs now');

      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('https://example.org');
      const title = await page.title();
      assert.equal(title, 'Example Domain');

      console.log('This logs too');
      await browser.close();
  })
});
```

Result:

[image]

The question has `jest` instead of `mocha`. Here is the code for `jest` and result. Which is almost same except following line,

```
// assert.equal(title, 'Example Domain');
expect(title).toEqual('Example Domain');
```

Result:

[image]

Optionally if you want to stack the logs together, you can pass `--verbose=false` when running `jest`.

[image]